# Prove that a local diffemorphism $f$ preserves the Gauss measure if and only if some condition is met

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, ergodic-theory

I was reading through [these lecture notes](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~tpereir1/ErgodicTheory_LecNotes.pdf) and found this exercise (page 6)

> Let $f:U\rightarrow U$ be a local $C^1$ diffeomorphism, and let $\rho$ be a continuous function. Show that $f$ preserves the measure $\mu=\rho m$ if and only if
>   $$\sum_{x\in f^{-1}(y)} \frac{\rho(x)}{|\mbox{det}Df(x)|}=\rho(y).$$

From the context, it looks like $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\mu$ the Gauss measure. How does one go about proving something like this?

EDIT: for context, the Gauss measure is defined as follows

$$\mu(B) = \frac{1}{\log 2}\int_B \frac{1}{1+x}dx.$$

For a function $f$ to preserve a measure $\mu$ means that
$$\mu(f^{-1}(B))=\mu(B)$$
for any measurable $B$.

The lecture notes don't say this explicitly, but I'd imagine $U$ is some open set.

Comment: What is the set $U$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. the lecture note's don't say

Comment: In that case the question isn't well-posed.

Comment: @UmbertoP. true - I'd imagine it's some open set, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the confusion: the statement you are trying to prove is general and unrelated to the Gauss measure.

Apply the *area formula*. For any integrable function $u : U \to \mathbb R$ you have $$\int_{f^{-1}(U)} u(x) |\det Df(x)| \, dx = \int_U \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} u(x) \, dy.$$

If $B \subset U$ is measurable you can take $\displaystyle u(x) = \frac{\chi_{f^{-1}(B)}(x)}{|\det Df(x)|} \rho(x)$ so that the left hand side reduces to $\displaystyle \int_{f^{-1}(B)} \rho(x) \, dx = \mu(f^{-1}(B))$.

Now focus on the right side. $\chi_{f^{-1}(B)}(x) = 1$ if and only if $f(x) \in B$ so that the integral equals $$\int_B \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} \frac{\rho (x)}{|\det Df(x)|} \, dx.$$ This equals $\mu(B)$ if and only if the integrand equals $\rho(y)$.

Comment: Where does the area formula come from?

Comment: That formula can be understood as a fixed point equation for the transfer operator. In general the idea is that fixed points of the transfer operator give you the density of invariant measure which are absolutely continuous with respect to the reference measure (in this case, the Lebesgue measure). The notes by Omri Sarig (which you can find on his website) are very good about this.